# Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties error - yet everything is initialized

Tags: swift, object

I'm running into this weird error.  it was working fine until I added the image and imageString values and then this error happened:

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

I thought I initialized all the properties, not sure why this error is happening.  Here is the custom object class

```
class JSONObject {
    private let baseImageURL = "https://website.com"

    var airbnbUS: Int
    var airbnbLocal: Int
    var imageString: String
    var image: URL

    init(airbnbUS: Int, airbnbLocal: Int, imageString: String, image: URL ){

        self.airbnbUS = airbnbUS
        self.airbnbLocal = airbnbLocal
        self.imageString = imageString
        self.image = image
    }

    init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){
        guard let cost = resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],
            let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String : Any],
            let usd = airbnb["USD"] as? Int,
            let chf = airbnb["CHF"] as? Int
            else {
                airbnbUS = 0
                airbnbLocal = 0
                return
        }

        airbnbUS = usd
        airbnbLocal = chf

        guard let media = (resultsDictionary["media"] as? [String: Any]),
            let imageDictionary = media["image"] as? [String: Any],
            let image1000 = imageDictionary["1000"] as? String
            else {
                imageString = ""
                image = URL(string: "\(baseImageURL)")!
                return
        }
        imageString = image1000
        image = URL(string: "\(baseImageURL)\(imageString)")!
    }
}
```

Comment: try init? because there are some validations(if let, guard) in your init(resultsDictionary)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `resultsDictionary` initializer. The `return` in your first `guard` statement could return from the initializer early, and the following `guard` statement (and the code where you assign the `image` and `imageString` properties) might not execute.

One solution is to change the first `guard` statement to an `if-let` statement.

```
init(resultsDictionary:[String: Any]){

    if let cost = resultsDictionary["cost"] as? [String: Any],
        let airbnb = cost["airbnb_median"] as? [String : Any],
        let usd = airbnb["USD"] as? Int,
        let chf = airbnb["CHF"] as? Int
        {
            airbnbUS = usd
            airbnbLocal = chf
    } else {
        airbnbUS = 0
        airbnbLocal = 0
    }

    guard let media = (resultsDictionary["media"] as? [String: Any]),
        let imageDictionary = media["image"] as? [String: Any],
        let image1000 = imageDictionary["1000"] as? String
        else {
            imageString = ""
            image = URL(string: "\(baseImageURL)")!
            return
    }
    imageString = image1000
    image = URL(string: "\(baseImageURL)\(imageString)")!
}
```

Comment: I see, there are many more values that have to be initialized, do you think using if let is better than using guard in this situation?

Comment: In doesn't matter too much, it's mostly preference. Although in this case I would probably use the nil-coalescing operator (`??`) in order to provide default values in case some entries are `nil`.